# SSIS - How to read an email column on the csv file and send the file as email attached

Tags: ssis

I need help.

I have a package that create several files and each file has an email column so how can I read this email column and send the file as email attached. I have a folder with 100 files and the email is different for each of them.

Thanks in advance.

Leo

Comment: Are the files in the same format? How can you read the email address..

Comment: Yes all the files are the same format.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use Foreach Loop Container to loop through all the Files and assign the FilePath to a variable(V1) while looping.
2. In ForEach Loop use an ExecuteSql Task to read the Email column and assign the value to another Variable(V2).
3. Use the above variables to send the email attachments(V1) to a particular Email ID(V2) by configuring Email Properties.

You can query an Excel like a Normal table.Your Excel SheetName will be your Table Name.[Click here to view an example to fetch data from excel using Sql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bMYw.png)

Comment: How do propose to do step 2 with execute SQL?